# Hide port with gunicorn and nginx

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

The Flask server starts at port 5000. With gunicorn and nginx, when I typed `http://localhost:80` (or `http://localhost`) in browser, the browser redirects to `http://localhost:5000`.

I added a few lines in the nginx config file

```
location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

How can I hide port(5000 in this case) after redirection? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you show us your nginx configuration file?

Comment: I added the config content in the post.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should structure your configuration file:

```
server {
    # listen on port 80
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

A server block is a subset of Nginx’s configuration that defines a virtual server used to handle requests of a defined type.

A location block lives within a server block and is used to define how Nginx should handle requests for different resources and URIs (the part of the request that comes after the domain name or IP address/port) for the parent server

[How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)